# Automator Quick Look workflow Finder Previews are different. Why and How?

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

As of 2021 when creating an Automator Quick Action Automator will attach a small grainy 3kb icon when saving a Quick Action .workflow file.

Looking at my Services folder I see all of the Quick Action .workflow files I have created over the years. When selecting one and hitting the space bar a Finder preview pops up and I see a few variations which impact the .workflow file size.

There doesn't seem to be any way to save a Quick Action .workflow file that will result in version 2 or 3 any longer.

Taking a look inside the package there are differences. Some contain a Preview.png and others do not. Some have a background.color and others do not.

I am trying to understand under what circumstances these variations occur so I can choose between the way the preview displays. Copying an icon and pasting it into the files info box does not change the preview image but it does change the Finder icon. It also doesn't alter the package content. I noticed that before saving a workflow if I choose a custom icon instead of the stock icons the icon is hardcoded into the xml in the.workflow file inside the package.

Using `xattr` as well has no affect on the package content.

Type 1
[image: Type1]

Type 2
[image: Type2]

Type 3
[image: Type3]

EDIT: Wanted to add that when choosing a "type" inside Automator a window pops up that has icons for each type. Two of the three icons shown actually create files that have the same icon when shown in finder. For some odd reason service workflows have a bizarre 3kb icon in lieu of the gear icon shown in this window.

EDIT2: Looking into this and tinkering around I see if choose to save a as a workflow and not a service I get a type 2 Finder Quick Look Finder preview.
If I don't touch the icon or background menus I get a type 1 Finder Quick Look preview.
If I add a "Get Specified Finder Items" Action to the workflow then I get a Type 3 Finder Quick Look preview.

[image: Type Window]